# border-bottom on hover issue and text auto center

Tags: html, css

I have a header in which a table menu is placed, however I run into some issues when trying to make a `border-bottom` appear when you hover over the specific `td`'s, the `border-bottom` will appear when you hover over it, but the border will stay when you hover to another part of the page. (The border appears a couple of pixels above the bottom border of the header as well.)*I already resolved this issue myself, forgot to remove a `calc()` statement earlier

Also I'm wondering why the text in the `td`'s gets automatically vertically centered. Maybe I'm overlooking something, please help?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
#header_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
#menu_container {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#menu_container tr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#menu_container td {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(203, 207, 218);
  font-family: Signika;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.menuItem {
  padding-top: 14px;
  border: 0;
}
.menuItem:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
#logo {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header_container">
    <table id="menu_container">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img id="logo" src="img/desygn%20logo%20website.png">
        </td>
        <td class="menuItem">Home</td>
        <td class="menuItem">Over</td>
        <td class="menuItem">Contact</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me... is this *all* the markup?  which browser are you using?

Comment: Vertical centering or rather vertical-align: middle is inherited from default browser styling. But more importantly, you really should look not use <table>s to markup a navigation menu.

Comment: `td`s have `vertical-align:center` by default, to align the data better visually. If you want to change that, you can, of course.

Comment: @ochi I'm using Safari, it's currently the fastest option for me. This is indeed all the markup, however there's a main.css file which has some `@font-face` rules in it but they wouldn't change anything about the layout

Comment: By the way, `margin-left:0 auto` is an error; it will be ignored by the browsers.

Comment: @Neps yeah it was kind of a tryout thingy, I prefer using divs instead

Comment: Can you explain your remark "I'm using Safari, it's currently the fastest option for me"? It doesn't compute. Also, you say the header has a bottom border, but there is none.

Comment: Also, off topic, but do you mean "about" by "over"?

Comment: @MrLister I guess what I meant by the Safari remark is that it's the best option for me, chrome takes up a lot of ram for my old Mac Mini, and I just dislike Firefox and Opera. And I'm sorry about my grammatical error from earlier.

Comment: @YSbakker The answer works for you ?

Answer (score 1):

The logo image size disturbing safari browser,which has been fixed with

```
#logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Hope this solution fine for you :)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}
#header_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
#menu_container {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#menu_container tr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#menu_container td {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(203, 207, 218);
  font-family: Signika;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.menuItem {
  padding-top: 14px;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid  rgb(50, 50, 50);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menuItem:hover {
  border-bottom-color: blue;
}
#logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header_container">
    <table id="menu_container">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img id="logo" src="img/desygn%20logo%20website.png">
        </td>
        <td class="menuItem">Home</td>
        <td class="menuItem">Over</td>
        <td class="menuItem">Contact</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Well, it kind of works, but just not the way I want it to. +1 for the effort though, I'm fixing my problem another way.

Comment: I guess that will be by getting rid of the table and replacing it with separate divs

Comment: That was what I was trying to say, it works indeed but I found an alternate way to solve my issue, therefore I'm not "happy" with your answer if that's the way you like to put it. However, it does indeed work and that's why I'm giving you an upvote.